# Is there any way to hide author information from custom article rather than content type?

Tags: 8, nodes

I know that I can hide author information in below path in Drupal 8:

```
Home>Admin>Structure>Types>Article>Display settings
```

but I want to know is there any setting or selective options to hide author information per custom article or post, rather than all post of custom content type?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, but it would be easy to implement:

1. Add a Boolean field called show_author_info or something
2. Create a node template for that content type in your theme (or for nodes in general if you don't need to specify a type)
3. Add a conditional to the template to only output the author information if the node has a positive value for that field